# Is it worth replacing valve seals on a car with 200K kms?

Tags: honda, valve, seal, jazz

I have a honda jazz 2003 gd1 1.3 with 200K kms on the clock. The car started burning oil around an year ago and occasionally (when the oil is topped up) puffing blue smoke puffs through the exhaust on start. No smoke under the bonnet or signs of oil leakage on the rocker cover.

While inspecting the spark plugs (it has 8, two per cylinder) I've noticed two of them, from two different cylinders, were slightly contaminated with oil. All the other ones had some carbonisation build up on the edges, after having replacing them only 1 year ago. Also, when running the engine with the oil cap removed, I can notice a "blowby". Not sure if this  necessarily means that the cylinder rings are worn or if it might just be the PCV valve.

While researching how to replace the valve seals, didn't seemed to be too much of a job as it seems like it can be done just by removing the rocker cover and using a piece of thick rope to fill the empty space on the cylinder (to make sure the valves doesn't get dropped inside them) while replacing the seals.

Questions are:

- is it worth the effort and time, given the car's age and how many kms the engine has done?
- do I need other tools other than a valve spring compressor tool, pliers, socket and torque wrenches?
- do I need any other parts other than rocker cover seals and valve seals?

I understand that probably, sometime soon, something else might need repairing, but my other options are:

- engine reconditioning = AUD$3000
- engine swap = AUD$2000
- selling as it is = maybe AUD$700
- selling to wreckers = maybe AUD$250

Comment: How much will you spend on a replacement vehicle and then how much to get it serviced, tires etc?

Comment: You mean while the job is being done? If so, none became I don't need one. Good point though.

Comment: So sell it to the wreckers and get a bike...

Comment: When I looked into replacing valve seals on a GMC Vortec engine , it required removing the heads, and compressing the valve springs to remove the retainers. I sold it.

Comment: Compressing the valve spring yes, inevitably. That's necessary for removing the valves or just for replacing the seals. But from what I've seen on youtube, on some cars it can be done with the head on.

Comment: @blacksmith37 we would take the sparkplug out, feed in a whole bunch of baler twine (string) then rotate the engine to push that piston up... used a ring spanner to push down the valve spring to get the collets out - changed the valve seal then continue with the others... ran fine after...

Comment: @Solar Mike that's how I've seen some guys doing it on youtube. I read on a thread here that you should never turn the engine crank backwards when using this method, I wonder why though. I don't have enough reps to comment on that thread.

Comment: Sometimes you have to, to get the string back out... but if the timing jumps a tooth... which can happen.

Comment: Another way is to lock the engine in position and apply compressed air to the relevant cylinder...

Comment: But that requires a compressor, not everyone has one. Jumping a tooth on the timing,  when turning the crank back, it's a risk only for engines with cambelts or it might also happen with chain driven ones?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the head is torqued on properly? It might be worth having a look before you start major work.